# testear un servicio WCF en postman

Tags: c#, wcf, postman

Se tiene un Servicio WCF en c# y se requiere testear desde postman en una máquina que no se tiene WCF Test Client asi, que se utiliza postman

segun este [blog](https://www.returngis.net/2018/07/llamar-a-un-servicio-soap-con-wcf-desde-postman-o-fiddler/) me faltaba el Content-type: test-xml; charset=utf-8
 SOAPAction Content-Length
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el error que sale en el postman es un 400 bad request que posibles fallos se estarán realizando?

**UPDATE**: Se envian datos en el body, raw --> XML

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://XXXXXX.conceptosbasicarepository/IConceptosBasicaRepository/GuardarConcepto</Action>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
    <GuardarConcepto xmlns="http://XXXXXXXX.conceptosbasicarepository/">
        <ConceptoTo xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XM.svcCONCEPTO.TO" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <d4p1:CodigoConcepto>202</d4p1:CodigoConcepto>
            <d4p1:CodigoEntidad>AMRC</d4p1:CodigoEntidad>
            <d4p1:CodigoNegocio>02</d4p1:CodigoNegocio>
            <d4p1:Estado>D</d4p1:Estado>
            <d4p1:FechaFinal i:nil="true" />
            <d4p1:FechaInicial>2017-01-24T00:00:00</d4p1:FechaInicial>
```

El SOAPAction esta asi;

http://XX.svcXXXXX.core.conceptosrepository/IConceptosRepository/GuardarConcepto
el
Content-Length "550"

Comment: Content-Type debe ser Text/Xml, no test-xml. No indicas el valor que colocaste en el SOAPAction. El content-length debe ser el tamaño del Request.
El contenido que veo en el request no está completo. Falta cerrar el elemento ConceptoTo, GuardarConcepto, Body y Envelope. ¿Te faltaron datos?
Si compartes el wsdl del servicio WCF, podemos revisar qué hay que colocar en cada header y la correcta estructura del request.

Comment: Los headers deben quedar así:

Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: http://XX.svcXXXXX.core.conceptosrepository/IConceptosRepository/GuardarConcepto

Content-Length:550

Aunque todavía me queda la duda del contenido del Request (no es un xml bien formado).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error 400 generalmente indica que el mensaje está mal formado... Ahora bien, en Postman se debe configurar lo siguiente:

```
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://XX.svcXXXXX.core.conceptosrepository/IConceptosRepository/GuardarConcepto"
Content-Length: 550
```

Y debes asegurarte que en el contenido del request vaya  un mensaje bien formado de acuerdo al contrato del servicio. En tu caso, veo que el XML no está completo...
Al menos debería quedar así:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://XXXXXX.conceptosbasicarepository/IConceptosBasicaRepository/GuardarConcepto</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GuardarConcepto xmlns="http://XXXXXXXX.conceptosbasicarepository/">
      <ConceptoTo xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XM.svcCONCEPTO.TO" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <d4p1:CodigoConcepto>202</d4p1:CodigoConcepto>
        <d4p1:CodigoEntidad>AMRC</d4p1:CodigoEntidad>
        <d4p1:CodigoNegocio>02</d4p1:CodigoNegocio>
        <d4p1:Estado>D</d4p1:Estado>
        <d4p1:FechaFinal i:nil="true" />
        <d4p1:FechaInicial>2017-01-24T00:00:00</d4p1:FechaInicial>
      </ConceptoTo>
    </GuardarConcepto>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

y contener los elementos adicionals requeridos por el llamado.

Todavía me surge la duda de si el SOAPAction es correcto. Puedes confirmarlo revisando el wsdl.

Comment: Hola esta exactamente como lo describiste, y segun tu en los comentarios específicas que debe ir Text/Xml, el xml lo tome del wcf client que está bien formado